# How to get a function similar to the ELO ranking system

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I'm not an expert in maths.

I'm looking a function similar to the [ELO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) system in order to give the users a score.

Those are the requirements for the system:

- The score must be between -100 and 100
- The function should be something like F(old_score,delta)=new_score
- The default score of an user is 0
- The near a user is to a limit (positive or negative), the harder should be to reach it
- If a user is near a limit (positive or negative) and gain/lose points those points should not be "increased". See example 3

Examples:

1. Neutral zone, delta almost no change: `F(0,+5)=5`,  `F(10,-5)=5`,`F(0,-5)=-5`
2. Middle scores going to the limit, delta modified: `F(50,+10)=56`, `F(60,+10)=65`, `F(-50,-10)=-56`
3. Middle scores going away from the limit: `F(50,-10)=40`, `F(60,-10)=-50`
4. Limit scores, delta damped:`F(90,+10)=92`, `F(95,+10)=96`

Can you help me with that? Thank you

Comment: It's "Elo", not "ELO". It's not an abbreviation. It even says as much in the Wikipedia article you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

- If old_score*delta<0 then damp = 1

Otherwise

- If        old_score < -90 then damp = 2+(old_score/50)
- If -90 <  old_score < -10 then damp = 1.1+(old_score/100)
- If -10 <= old_score <  10 then damp = 1
- If  10 <= old_score <  90 then damp = 1.1-(old_score/100)
- If  90 <= old_score       then damp = 2-(old_score/50)

new_score = old_score+damp*delta